# How to program AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I want to encrypt `NSDictionary` type and send to backend: 
- AES-128 (key length 128 bit) in CBC mode.
- Padding process in accordance with ANSI X9.23 / ISO 10126-2.
How should I do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do that yourself. Just don't specify any padding and then the padding will be available in the decrypted data and can be removed.

ISO_10126 padding has been withdrawn and specified padding the last 8-byte block. Note that AES uses a 16-byte block so it really does not match.

Other than the 8/16 byte last block size both ISO_10126 and PKCS#7 padding have a last byte that specified the number of bytes of padding added. To remove the padding, assuming the decryption was successful, just get the last byte and remove the number of bytes based on the value.

See [ISO_10126 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#ISO_10126).

Finally, don't use ISO_10126 padding, use [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Comment: Thanks, that's help. Seems the only way I have to write myself